# How to find out if NVENC is supported

Tags: nvenc

Is there a Cuda call or even a Windows 7 call that will help me determine if NVENC is supported on a particular machine?

Thanks.

Comment: NVENC is not technically part of CUDA.  I understand that one of the ways to use NVENC is via CUDA resources (buffers) but it's essentially independent.  There is no CUDA runtime API call or driver API call that knows anything at all about NVENC.  Have you read the NVENC doc?  I believe there is a call for machine capability spelled out in the user guide.

Comment: Thanks, Robert. I have read the document, but, truthfully, it has been sometime. Time to revisit.

Comment: The call I was thinking of was `4.2.1.37 NVENCSTATUS NVENCAPI NvEncodeAPIGetMaxSupportedVersion (uint32_t  version)
This function can be used by clients to determine if the driver supports the NvEncodeAPI header the application was
compiled with.` which is on p45 of the `NvEncodeApi_v8.0.pdf` document available [here](https://developer.nvidia.com/nvidia-video-codec-sdk).  You'll need to be a registered developer to download it, I believe.

Comment: I am registered and will go look. Thank you!